# mongo schema design - bug in combination $or and sort

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing, database-schema

Implementing a social game where each profile can have many challenges with other profiles.
each challenge has only two related profiles called *opponents*.

In my current schema design I have **challenges** collection each document look's like...

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51e8de5be4b0131df7db33c6"),
"state" : "ACTIVE",
"move" : "b0fe109d9663a87e8450ed1299ae8927",
"creationTime" : ISODate("2013-07-19T06:36:11.228Z"),
"lastUpdateTime" : ISODate("2013-07-19T11:18:44.856Z"),
"round" : 1,
"opponent1" : {
     "pid" : "b0fe109d9663a87e8450ed1299ae8927",
     "firstName" : "",
     "lastName" : "",
     "imageUrl" : "",
     "unique" : "",
     "gender" : "male"
},
"opponent2" : {
     "pid" : "4fc84459576623099eeb96329c1243de",
     "firstName" : "",
     "lastName" : "",
     "imageUrl" : "",
     "unique" : "",
     "gender" : "male"
}
```

The challenge is stateless regarding to who is requesting it, which mean opponent1 and opponent2 will get the same document.

When I want to retrieve a specific profile challenges I am using the **$or** operator

```
Query:{ "$or" : [ { "opponent1.pid" : "profileID"} , { "opponent2.pid" : "profileID"}]}
Sort:{ "lastUpdateTime" : -1}
```

I have nested indexes as following

```
{ "opponent1.pid":1}
{ "opponent2.pid":1}
```

The thing is that there is an open bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205
which preventing from the above query to use the indexes (because the combination of $or and sort) and the queries are very slow.

Is there a way not to use the $or operator while remaining in the current schema and get the above query run faster?

all this issue got me thinking whether I should add new collection (lets call it **challenges_rel**) which will relate each profile to his challenges ( normalize the challenges collection a bit) but it seems like un-mongo approach isn't it? is there a better schema design to my humble needs?

Your answer is highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried do two queries (that is actually what mongodb does) and merge the result in your app?

Comment: You are finding on the subdocument only, sorting is always dodgy when you do it on a multi value field

Comment: @Sammaye the thing is the bug isn't related to sub documents it is the combination of $or and sorting .. if I don't sort the result all good.

Comment: @MiguelCartagena which two queries? do you mean 1) search in opponent1 2) search in opponent2 ? then what about the sort ? I also have page limit on the query .. by the way mongo runs these two queries in parallel ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205 and https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071 are slated to be fixed in MongoDB 2.5.x (2.6 release version). That should help you directly. In the meantime if you can modify your schema to store the opponents as an array you can perform this as an indexed query.
I modified your doc above as

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "state" : "ACTIVE",
        "move" : "b0fe109d9663a87e8450ed1299ae8927",
        "creationTime" : ISODate("2013-07-19T06:36:11.228Z"),
        "lastUpdateTime" : ISODate("2013-07-19T11:18:44.856Z"),
        "round" : 1,
        "opponents" : [
        {
                "pid" : "b0fe109d9663a87e8450ed1299ae8927",
                "firstName" : "",
                "lastName" : "",
                "imageUrl" : "",
                "unique" : "",
                "gender" : "male"
        },
        {
                "pid" : "4fc84459576623099eeb96329c1243de",
                "firstName" : "",
                "lastName" : "",
                "imageUrl" : "",
                "unique" : "",
                "gender" : "male"
        }
        ]
}
```

I also stored 2 other docs with _id 3 and 4 where I changed the pid in the elements (to prove it actually does the or).
Now the query uses the index

```
> db.foo.find({"opponents.pid":{$in:["b0fe109d9663a87e8450ed1299ae8927", "4fc844
59576623099eeb96329c1243de"]}}).sort({lastUpdateTime:-1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor opponents.pid_1_lastUpdateTime_-1 multi",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 3,
        "nscannedObjects" : 4,
        "nscanned" : 4,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 8,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 8,
        "scanAndOrder" : true,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "opponents.pid" : [
                        [
                                "4fc84459576623099eeb96329c1243de",
                                "4fc84459576623099eeb96329c1243de"
                        ],
                        [
                                "b0fe109d9663a87e8450ed1299ae8927",
                                "b0fe109d9663a87e8450ed1299ae8927"
                        ]
                ],
                "lastUpdateTime" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "sridhar-PC:27017"
}
```

Comment: Just about to write the same answer to my question , but you answered earlier :) btw in your explain "scanAndOrder" : true which means that the sorting don't use the index... just to let you know .. anyway thanks.